# Como fazer para checar se um usuário está com o email confirmado com somente uma query?

Tags: mysql

Possuo 2 tabelas, uma de usuários e uma de emails confirmados, que possui um FK do user e um bool de usuário confirmado:

```
- tbl_valida_email
=========================
fk_id_usuario
usuario_confirmado
```

Eu estava utilizando a seguinte query para isso:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email='email' AND senha='senha' AND (SELECT valido FROM tbl_valida_email WHERE id_usuario=(SELECT id FROM tbl_usuario WHERE email='email' AND senha='senha'));
```

E em minha opinião, ta complexo demais para uma uma coisa simples. Como melhora-la?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode vincular as duas tabelas com a cláusula `JOIN`. Utilizando `INNER JOIN` você só terá resultado caso existam registros nas duas tabelas.

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_usuario tu
       INNER JOIN tbl_valida_email tve ON tve.id_usuario = tu.id
 WHERE tu.email='email'
   AND tu.senha='senha'
   AND valido = TRUE;
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu queria, não sabia que o inner join era usado para isso. :O

Comment: @Francisco daqui a pouco coloco uma explicação mais detalhada